# YouTube API V3 404 error on getting my subscriptions

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have created new YouTube account for test purposes. I got an accessToken for this account and tried to get my own subscriptions via YouTubeAPI.
I use Google APIs Client Library for PHP.

```
$data = $service->subscriptions->listSubscriptions('snippet', ['mine' => 'true']);
```

I get an error:

"domain": "youtube.subscription",
"reason": "subscriberNotFound",
"message": "The subscriber identified with the request cannot be found.",
"locationType": "parameter",
"location": "channelId"
"code": 404,
"message": "The subscriber identified with the request cannot be found."

I tried to change the YouTube account, and I got a successful result on my old account. But I want to get info on my new account.
What the problem?

Comment: I noticed, when I create channel for new account, then this error happens. But if channel doesn't create for the new account, this function works perfectly.

Comment: Give the [Try-it](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) a go? Anyway, what's your expected outcome?

Comment: I expected a predictable API work. Documentation doesn't describe features of work for new accounts. Why must I guess how Google API working?